# Java/Groovy how to catch spring dao family of exceptions

Tags: spring, grails, groovy

I'm using Grails to implement a multi-thread process by a thread pool with each thread creating and saving a domain object Microblog. But it seems that whenever an exception takes place in any of the threads the thread pool is shut down. In my case a **org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException** caused a **java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException**, subsequently terminating my thread pool and all following logic.

I don't want this to happen so I want to catch all possible spring and hibernate exceptions when saving the domain object. In short, I'm wondering how to catch possible exceptions under the framework of Spring and Hibernate.

My multi-threading is like this:

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCount);
def threads=[];
for(int i=0;i<threadCount;i++){    
    threads.add(new MyThread(params));
}
try {
    //submit all threads to the pool
    List<Future> futures = threads.collect{theThread->
          es.submit({->
            theThread.run();
          });
        }
        futures.each{it.get()}
}finally {
        def notRun=es.shutdownNow();
        log.info "Now the thread pool is shut down. Still ${notRun} threads are not finished and stopped.";
}
```

In the implemented runnable class:

```
public MyThread implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run(){
        //some logic here
        Microblog.withTransaction{
            Microblog m=new Microblog(some params);
            try{
                m.save(flush:true);
                if(m.hasErrors()){log.error m.errors}
            }catch(//how to catch spring and hibernate exceptions in one catch?){//Some error handling here. At least the thread lives.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Appreciate your insightful ideas!

Comment: You've tried `catch(e)` to catch everything yeah?

Comment: @tim_yates Surely this can work. But of course you will prefer handling different exceptions in different blocks.

Comment: If you're bothered, you could multi-catch http://www.groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#_multi_catch

Comment: But more often than not, people over complicate exception handling

Comment: @tim_yates Thanks I get what you mean. My point is, you can not list every single exception you will meet and it's too general to catch them all in one block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using ThreadGroup.uncaughtException and/or Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.

In your catch block, you may catch all exceptions and then check if it is hibernate or spring like so:

```
catch(Exception e) {
if(e.getClass().getCanonicalName().beginsWith("org.springframework")) {
}
if(e.getClass().getCanonicalName().beginsWith("org.springframework")) {
}
}
```

Other option is to check if exception class is BaseException interface of Spring/Hibernate. Spring doesn't have it but you may try org.springframework.core.NestedRuntimeException. For Hibernate, you may use org.springframework.core.NestedRuntimeException.

Note that if you are just trying to catch all framework exceptions, then instead it may be a better idea to have an interface for exceptions that your code generates. You may catch that exception and then other exceptions like so:

```
catch(MyException me) {
} catch(Exception e) {
}
```

Comment: Sounds great! Personally I prefer the BaseException approach. Thanks for your detailed answer!

Comment: @OrlandoL You are welcome. You may also upvote the answer!